# Issue in reading a value from appsettings.Development.json

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a program that I want to publish as a single exe file which will be used by a user who can change the appsettings as they need. Some of the settings are just for development (included in appsettings.Development.json and this file is not published) and some of them are required for production (included in appsettings.json).
For better clarification consider the following code as appsettings.Development.json

```
{
   "SettingA":
   { 
     "ItemA" : "some value"
   },
   "SettingB": 
   {
    "ItemB": ["1010","2020","3030"]
   }
}
```

- SettingA is used by both development and production and the value can be changed by user
- SettingB is only used by development and the value **cannot** be changed by user

So the appsettings.json would be like, which is published for the user to change:

```
{
   "SettingA":
   { 
     "ItemA" : "some value"
   }
}
```

In order to use this program in production, SettingB is still needed to be set as default value like the following:

```
class SettingB
{
  public string[] ItemB {get; set;} = new string[]{"*"}
}
```

However, the issue is that when I want to use this in development I expect ItemB to be overriden by the values in appsettings.Development.json, instead I get this:

- What I expect: ItemB = {"1010","2020","3030"}
- What the result actually is: ItemB = {"*", "1010","2020","3030"}

It seems instead of being replaced, the values are added to the default one.

I have two questions here:

1. Is this approach of setting default values for such properties like SettingB, OK?
2. How can I get the expected value for ItemB?

By the way I use Options to read the settings.

Comment: What does it look like where you try to set `settingB` to `{"1010","2020","3030"}`? Can you show us the relevant code for that please?

Comment: It is exactly a string array of these values

Comment: So the code is `settingB = {"1010","2020","3030"};`?

Comment: I'm not sure what you exactly mean because the values in appsettings are read by options pattern. So there is no such code as you said explicitly.

Comment: Okay, can you please copy and paste your code where you do that so I can help you? I can't help you if I can't see your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my second question in this [article](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/overriding-an-array-configuration-object-4d93470e97d0). Surprisingly the arrays are merged by design!